# SQL procedure for inserting records in a table based on records in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a FormTable

```
| FormId | FormName | ParentLawId |  StartDate | Frequency |
|--------|----------|-------------|------------|-----------|
|      1 |    FormA |          21 | 2017-11-06 |   Monthly |
|      2 |    FormB |          22 | 2016-12-06 |    Yearly |
|      3 |    FormC |          24 | 2015-06-08 |  Quaterly |
|      4 |    FormD |          24 | 2018-02-11 |   Monthly |
```

I have another CalendarTable

```
| CalendarId | LawId |  StartDate | Frequency | FormId |
|------------|-------|------------|-----------|--------|
|          1 |    21 | 2017-11-06 |   Monthly |      1 |
|          2 |    24 | 2015-06-08 |  Quaterly |      3 |
```

I want to insert records in CalendarTable for the forms(in FormTable) which do not have their respective records in the CalendarTable.

For example, the final CalendarTable should be

```
| CalendarId | LawId |  StartDate | Frequency | FormId |
|------------|-------|------------|-----------|--------|
|          1 |    21 | 2017-11-06 |   Monthly |      1 |
|          2 |    24 | 2015-06-08 |  Quaterly |      3 |
|          3 |    22 | 2016-12-06 |    Yearly |      2 |
|          4 |    24 | 2018-02-11 |   Monthly |      4 |
```

So, 2 new records have been generated in CalendarTable corresponding to FormId(FormTable) column, and rest of the column values in CalendarTable  should be as it is in corresponding columns from FormTable

SQL Fiddle for Schema of the two Tables

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e337d0/1

Comment: What have you coded till now? and where you stuck?

Comment: I have not coded anything yet, I am thinking about writing an SQL procedure because I need to insert over 500 records. I am just not sure whether writing Procedure is the right solution yet.

Comment: @KeithMachado  your calendarid should be auto increnmented right

Comment: @Gagan Burde that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query inside your stored procedure

Note:keeping calender id as autoincrement

```
insert into CalendarTable(LawId, StartDate, Frequency, FormId)
select ParentLawId,StartDate,Frequency,FormId
from FormTable  where formid not in(select formid from CalendarTable);
```

Comment: Will this work for all records or just one? Or do I have to run this statement inside a for loop?@Gagan Burde

Comment: it will work for all records whose form id is not present in calender CalendarTable.Please mark this as answer if it helps